# Is "any sort of an explanation" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

My gut tells me no, and it should be "any sort of explanation", but I just came across it in something [Roger Ebert wrote](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/bronson-2009).

> I suppose, after all, Nicolas Winding Refn, the director and co-writer of "Bronson," was wise to leave out **any sort of an explanation**.

Google apparently supports my gut feeling, with lopsided search results. But can anyone explain it?

Comment: Well, without the article it sounds fine but it doesn't sound wrong with one either.

Answer (score 1):

This is idiomatic, and well-established in some varieties of English. For example, a person who feels as if his or her intelligence is being underestimated might say "what **sort of an** idiot do you think I am?" A person asked about the categorization of a Jackalope might very well offer the statement "**it's a sort of a** horned rabbit."